# Notify Icon doesn't show on different os

Tags: c#, forms

I created program in Windows 10 OS but notify icon doesn't show up in my second computer that runs Windows 7. Here is code for notify icon:

```
notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Exclamation;
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Licenca";
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Warning;
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Some text.";
notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(3000);
notifyIcon1.Dispose();
```

Comment: I'm surprised it shows up on Win10... `notifyIcon1.Dispose()` destroys the icon. Just remove this line.

Comment: @Quadrition does it show up or does it not even show up.

Comment: it doesn't at all @UnknownDeveloper

Comment: Yea it works now... I am confused too... @ThomasLevesque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`notifyIcon1.Dispose()` destroys the icon, so it disappears immediately. You should remove this line. Also, make sure that `notifyIcon1.Visible` is set to true, or the icon will never show up.